# SwiftUI DatePicker constraint conflict

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to add date picker to my app, but when I add it I get warning messages about constraints. And the message is:

> 2023-02-28 13:46:35.521600+0200 Warranty Safe[14957:3417410] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
> Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
> Try this:
> (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
> (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
> (
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282795090 H:|-(>=0)-[UILabel:0x129e5a180]   (active, names: '|':_UIDatePickerLinkedLabel:0x129e59d70 )>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282795220 UILayoutGuide:0x283dc33a0''.trailing == UILabel:0x129e5a180.trailing   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2827952c0 _UIDatePickerCompactDateLabel:0x129e59990.leading == _UIDatePickerLinkedLabel:0x129e59d70.leading - 12   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282795450 UIView:0x129e5abf0.trailing == UILayoutGuide:0x283dc33a0''.trailing + 12   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2827959a0 H:|-(12)-[UILabel:0x129e616f0]   (active, names: '|':_UIDatePickerCompactTimeLabel:0x129e5b170 )>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282795a40 H:[UILabel:0x129e616f0]-(12)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIDatePickerCompactTimeLabel:0x129e5b170 )>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2827968a0 H:[UIView:0x129e5abf0]-(4)-[_UIDatePickerCompactTimeLabel:0x129e5b170]   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2827968f0 _UIDatePickerCompactDateLabel:0x129e59990.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x283dc3720''.leading   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282796940 _UIDatePickerCompactTimeLabel:0x129e5b170.trailing <= UILayoutGuide:0x283dc3720''.trailing   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282796ad0 H:|-(>=0)-UILayoutGuide:0x283dc3720''   (active, names: '|':_UIDatePickerIOSCompactView:0x129e59530 )>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282796b20 UILayoutGuide:0x283dc3720''.right == _UIDatePickerIOSCompactView:0x129e59530.right   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2827961c0 H:|-(0)-[_UIDatePickerIOSCompactView:0x129e59530]   (active, names: '|':UIDatePicker:0x129e59300 )>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282796440 _UIDatePickerIOSCompactView:0x129e59530.trailing == UIDatePicker:0x129e59300.trailing   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2827978e0 '_UITemporaryLayoutWidth' UIDatePicker:0x129e59300.width == 0   (active)>"
> )Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
> <NSLayoutConstraint:0x282795220 UILayoutGuide:0x283dc33a0''.trailing == UILabel:0x129e5a180.trailing   (active)>

In general it is quite larger, but I think it was repeating it self.
In my app I use this section inside the Form

```
Section {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        DatePicker("Select purchase date", selection: $handler.purchaseDate, displayedComponents: .date)
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                            .labelsHidden()
                        Divider()
                            .frame(height: 1)
                            .background(Color("Acent"))
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("Date of purchase:")
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
```

But I experimented and added to the WindowGroup just the DatePicker and the console gave me the same warning.
Maybe some body know that this is just some Xcode bug?

Comment: running Xcode 14.2 and Simulator iOS 16.2 I cannot reproduce the error. Should be fine.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I forgot to tell that it was on device not simulator.

Comment: I still think it should be fine :)

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this on a real iOS device. However, we do not have access to your `handler` object, so we cannot fully debug - would you please paste the code for that into your question? Also, it looks like this might be an issue with the constraints - are you using a pure SwiftUI lifecycle, or do you have any UIKit pieces of code?